# WSDL customization - binding name

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I would like to know what will be the "binding" name in the **WSDL** file when the following WebService is deployed:

```
@WebService (name="LogService", serviceName="LogWebService")  
 public class LogServiceImpl 
 {    
 public void log(String msg) {       
 System.out.println(msg);    
 } 
 }
```

As far as I know it should be **SIB** + "Port" +"Binding", namely **LogServiceImplPortBinding** since the "portname" does not appear in the **@WebService** annotation. Otherwise (in case it appeared) it would be "portname" + "Binding". Someone states though that the "binding" name is in this case "name" +"Binding", namely **LogServiceBinding** because the "name" appears in the annotation. What is correct? In what tutorial or specification is this customization described?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be something like this: serviceName+"SoapBinding"
So in this case: LogWebServiceSoapBinding

Maybe this link will help you to get the difference between "name" and "serviceName"
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jws/WebService.html

But the better way to know, is to test! So try to deploy this service and check the binding name in the wsdl.